# why I get a 419 page error when logging back into laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am writing applications in laravel and I have a problem after logging in to the application and turning off the browser and then restarting the application, error 419 comes out

is  .env file:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DOMAIN_URL=.my domain
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=960
```

and file session.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "dynamodb", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 960),

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
    | automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
    |
    */

    'encrypt' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | While using one of the framework's cache driven session backends you may
    | list a cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value
    | must match with one of the application's configured cache "stores".
    |
    | Affects: "apc", "dynamodb", "memcached", "redis"
    |
    */

    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you when it can't be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP Access Only
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
    | value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
    | the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
    |
    */

    'http_only' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Same-Site Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
    | take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
    | will set this value to "lax" since this is a secure default value.
    |
    | Supported: "lax", "strict", "none", null
    |
    */

    'same_site' => 'lax',

];
```

entering the application page after correctly logging in and then turning off the page and after re-logging in, a page error 419 pops up, then when you enter the path manually, e.g.
.my domain.pl/home the application starts without any problems, but otherwise error 419 pops up, I don't know why

Comment: Error 419 pops up when the csrf token is not present, or expired. is @csrf included in your form?

Comment: this is    ``` <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}"> @csrf <div class="mb-3"> <label for="adres e-mail" class="form-label ">Zaloguj się</label> <input class="form-control" type="text" id="emailaddress" required="" placeholder="Wpisz adres e-mail" @error('email') is-invalid @ enderror name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" autofocus> </div> ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup CSRF https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf

#### Introduction

Cross-site request forgeries are a type of malicious exploit whereby unauthorized commands are performed on behalf of an authenticated user. Thankfully, Laravel makes it easy to protect your application from cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attacks.

#### An Explanation Of The Vulnerability

In case you're not familiar with cross-site request forgeries, let's discuss an example of how this vulnerability can be exploited. Imagine your application has a /user/email route that accepts a POST request to change the authenticated user's email address. Most likely, this route expects an email input field to contain the email address the user would like to begin using.

Without CSRF protection, a malicious website could create an HTML form that points to your application's /user/email route and submits the malicious user's own email address:

```
<form action="https://your-application.com/user/email" method="POST">
    <input type="email" value="malicious-email@example.com">
</form>

<script>
    document.forms[0].submit();
</script>
```

If the malicious website automatically submits the form when the page is loaded, the malicious user only needs to lure an unsuspecting user of your application to visit their website and their email address will be changed in your application.

To prevent this vulnerability, we need to inspect every incoming POST, PUT, PATCH, or DELETE request for a secret session value that the malicious application is unable to access.

Preventing CSRF Requests
Laravel automatically generates a CSRF "token" for each active user session managed by the application. This token is used to verify that the authenticated user is the person actually making the requests to the application. Since this token is stored in the user's session and changes each time the session is regenerated, a malicious application is unable to access it.

The current session's CSRF token can be accessed via the request's session or via the csrf_token helper function:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/token', function (Request $request) {
    $token = $request->session()->token();

    $token = csrf_token();

    // ...
});
```

Anytime you define a "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", or "DELETE" HTML form in your application, you should include a hidden CSRF _token field in the form so that the CSRF protection middleware can validate the request. For convenience, you may use the @csrf Blade directive to generate the hidden token input field:

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
    @csrf

    <!-- Equivalent to... -->
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
</form>
```

The App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken middleware, which is included in the web middleware group by default, will automatically verify that the token in the request input matches the token stored in the session. When these two tokens match, we know that the authenticated user is the one initiating the request.

CSRF Tokens & SPAs
If you are building an SPA that is utilizing Laravel as an API backend, you should consult the Laravel Sanctum documentation for information on authenticating with your API and protecting against CSRF vulnerabilities.

Excluding URIs From CSRF Protection
Sometimes you may wish to exclude a set of URIs from CSRF protection. For example, if you are using Stripe to process payments and are utilizing their webhook system, you will need to exclude your Stripe webhook handler route from CSRF protection since Stripe will not know what CSRF token to send to your routes.

Typically, you should place these kinds of routes outside of the web middleware group that the App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider applies to all routes in the routes/web.php file. However, you may also exclude the routes by adding their URIs to the $except property of the VerifyCsrfToken middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
        'http://example.com/foo/bar',
        'http://example.com/foo/*',
    ];
}
```

Comment: csrf is in the login form

Comment: ``` <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="emailaddress" class="form-label">Login</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="emailaddress" required="" placeholder="Wpisz adres e-mail" @error('email') is-invalid @enderror name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" autofocus>

                            </div>
```

Comment: @HubertGościniak CSRF is required for all POST API Requests. just set `protected $except = ["*"];` as a quick hack to just allow all API POST Requests without CSRF